# Find area of a simple, smooth, closed curve lying in a plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration, plane-curves, surfaces

I was given this question in class and I assume it is a spin off of Green's theorem for finding the area of a closed curve $\lambda$ in 2D but expanded to 3D I believe. Anyways I am pretty confused about it so if anyone could help I would appreciate it,.

Question: Let $\lambda$ be a simple closed smooth space curve that lies in a plane with
unit normal vector n = (a, b, c) and has positive orientation with re-
spect to the normal vector n of the plane. Show that the plane area
enclosed by $\lambda$ is $$\frac12 \int_{\lambda} (bz-cy)dx + (cx-az)dy + (ay-bx)dz$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Green's theorem we know takes the form for the area enclosed by a closed curve:

$$A = \iint_A dx \, dy = \frac{1}{2} \oint_C (-y\, dx + x\, dy) = \frac{1}{2} \oint_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$$

where $\vec{F}=(-y,x,0)$ and $d\vec{r} = (dx,dy,dz)$.  Note that this is for the $xy$ plane, in which the normal vector is $\hat{n}=(0,0,1)$.  You can see that, for a position vector $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$:

$$\hat{n} \times \vec{r} = \vec{F}$$

This is true in general.  For an arbitrary plane in which $\hat{n}=(a,b,c)$,

$$\vec{F}=\hat{n} \times \vec{r} = (b z-c y,c x-a z,a y-b x)$$

Therefore

$$A =  \frac{1}{2} \oint_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} = \frac{1}{2} \oint_C [(b z-c y) dx + (c x-a z) dy + (a y-b x) dz]$$

as was to be shown.

Comment: Ok, I understand that dr = (dx,dy,dz). Where I am confused is how n x r = F...? So n = (a,b,c) is normal to the plane curve. Is r = (x,y,z) just a position vector that is on the surface of the curve? I see how it all comes together but I just can't see where r x n = F comes from.

Comment: I was trying to illustrate by analogy to the simple case you already know.  $\hat{n} \times \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$ is coordinate independent, so if it computes an area in the $xy$ plane, it does so for any plane.

Comment: where does the 1/2 come from?

Comment: Each of the area elements of the integrand represents an infinitesimal  triangular element with respect to a common 3rd point in the interior of the closed curve; the area of this element is one-half of a determinant formed by these points, which turns out to be the integrand.  See, for example, this: http://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/matrices/applications.html

Comment: Ok, so it comes from taking small triangles from the surface and when you find the area you just take the 1/2 out of the integration...?

Comment: @user68203: yes.

Comment: Ok, I am still confused however at how you can say n x r = F. I can see it in your explanation above but how is this applicable to objects in 3 space? Or is this true always? I am looking through my books and I can't see anything like this. Like I kind of understand what is going on but I can't get around that. Could you maybe explain that further or differently?

Comment: Nvm, I understand it now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @user68203: OK.  I was just going to say that it follows from a formula for the cross product and the generic area of a differentiable closed curve.  But I am glad you got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is immidiate using the stoke's theorem where $S$ being surface measure and $A$ be surface enclosed by the curve, you take
$$ f(x,y,z) = (1/2)(bz-cy,cx-az,ay-bx) $$ And you find $ curl(f) = (a,b,c) = n $. and you have $n.n = 1 $ and $\partial A = \lambda $. so from stoke's theorem you get area of the surface S(A) as 
$$ S(A) = \int_A dS = \int_A curl(f).n dS = \int_{\partial A} f.dr 
 = \frac{1}{2}\int_\lambda (bz-cy)dx + (cx-az)dy + (ay-bx) dz $$